# Pythagoras tree bounding size

Tags: limits, trees, fractals

The Pythagoras tree is a fractal generated by squares. For each square, two new smaller squares are constructed and connected by their corners to the original square. The angle of the triangle formed can be varied.

[image]

The problem is finding the size of the bounding box (to a certain precision) for this fractal. The graph is essentially a rooted tree. Each node represents a square with a certain size and orientation. The tree is infinitely deep. For a certain precision, the problem is easily solved with a computer using branch and bound. I want to know if there are any estimates or hard limits on the size. Any bounds on the area of the fractal are also appreciated.

The isosceles right triangle case gives a nice bounding box of $6 \times 4$, which can be calculated easily with a geometric series. Other cases are more difficult for me (the maximal tree paths follow a zigzag pattern - for a while).

Comment: It seems there's no upper bound on the height of such boxes, considering the sequence of fractals where the right triangle becomes closer and closer to degenerate.

Comment: @GregMartin I mean for a certain case of triangle (ex. 30-60-90)

Comment: You asked several questions; I answered one of them.

Comment: Are you doing https://projecteuler.net/problem=395 ? In order not to ruin the fun, I will only give you a hint: at the $i$-th iteration, although $2^i$ squares are added, there are only $i + 1$ different shapes and positions.

Comment: Not just the width and the height, also the position of the first square within the bounding box would be nice to know.

Comment: What you mean with the area of the fractal?

Comment: @san the total area covered by the squares and triangles, with overlapped areas only counting once. The wikipedia article says "not much is known about $A$"